# get velocity variables from the template

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, velocity, template-engine

I am dealing with some velocity templates in my nodejs application. I am using [npm velocity package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/velocity). Is there a way to get a list of all the variables in the templates?

Comment: and also all the data structures like arrays